# String values changed, when saving in multi-array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, input, foreach

I extract from db and save date and hour string, in array:

```
$array_likes_Days=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT time  , totalLikesDay  FROM pstableliker WHERE likeUrl='".$url_selec."' AND totalLikesDay !=0 ;");
$arrayDateHours;
$cont1=0; 
$cont2=0; 
foreach ($array_likes_Days as $key => $row) {

    $arrayDateHours[$cont1]=substr($row->time, 0, -9);
    var_dump(substr($row->time, 0, -9).'__'.$arrayDateHours[$cont1]);

    $arrayDateHours[$cont1][$cont2]=date('H:i', strtotime($row->time));
    var_dump(substr($row->time, 0, -9).'__'.$arrayDateHours[$cont1]);

    $cont1++;
    $cont2++;
    }
```

In the first var_dump the output: `2015-07-21__2015-07-21` everything goes well.

But after save hour in this line: `$arrayDateHours[$cont1][$cont2]=date('H:i', strtotime($row->time));` The second var_dump output:`2015-07-21__0015-07-21` show that the value of the array is changed to:`2015-07-21->0015-07-21`,  Why this happen when saving in a multi-array?

I want to save date and hours in array like this:

```
2015-07-21-->01:24
          -->04:12
          -->12:40
```

Comment: You are define date as index of array. Change from `$arrayDateHours[$cont1][$cont2]` to `$arrayDateHours[$cont2]`

Comment: @Hassan Because i want to save the date and hours of that date in array, I just update the question

Comment: you are not storing substr($row->time, 0, -9) anywhere you should store it in variable and use that for storing in $arrayDateHours[$cont1][$cont2]

Comment: @hassan That will just overwrite the first assignment... $arrayDateHours[$cont1] needs to be an array that contains the date elements as one element and the time range as the second.

Comment: @Orangepill You say that the only way to save date and her hours is in array independently for each date and then save that array in a multi-array?

Comment: no not the only way... I was mainly saying that the way you are doing it now you are screwing up your first assignment (of a string) during the second assignment (which you are using the string as an array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$data = ['2015-08-19 05:11:44', '2015-08-19 05:15:11', '2015-08-19 05:17:38'];

//echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());
$arrayDateHours = array();

$i = 0;
foreach($data as $time)
{
    $time = explode(' ', $time);

    $arrayDateHours[$time[0]][$i] = $time[1];
    $i++;
}

var_dump($arrayDateHours);
```

OUTPUT

```
array (size=1)
  '2015-08-19' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '05:11:44' (length=8)
      1 => string '05:15:11' (length=8)
      2 => string '05:17:38' (length=8)
```

Comment: The $i is unnecessary in this case. `$arrayDateHours[$time[0]][] = $time[1];` will work just fine.

Comment: @RobertoMassimoPataraBrianco I'm glad it for you :)

Comment: @RobertoMassimoPataraBrianco yes `$arrayDateHours[$time[0]][] = $time[1];` will give you same result.

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing this line

```
$arrayDateHours[$cont1][$cont2]=date('H:i', strtotime($row->time));
```

with

```
$arrayDateHours[$cont1][]=date('H:i', strtotime($row->time));
```

It will save data in array as

```
$arrayDateHours= array(1) {  ["2015-07-21"]=>  array(2) {    
  [0]=>
  string(1) "01:24"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "04:12"    } }
```